react-native ios done button in chrome not triggering event onSubmitEditing
In Chrome on ios when browsing a react-native site with a 
there are two buttons 'Done' above the keyboard and the 'Enter' key on the bottom right,
both should trigger 'onSubmitEditing' but only the enter key works in chrome on an ios device
<TextInput 
   ref={inputRef}
   style={styles.SearchInputMob} 
   multiline={false}
   placeholder="Keyword..."
   placeholderTextColor='grey'
   onFocus={()=>setKeyVisable(true)}
   onBlur={()=>handleBlur()}
   onSubmitEditing={()=>handleBlur()}
   onChangeText={handleInputChange}
                            
   value={searchText}
/>

In safari both buttons trigger 'onSubmitEditing'
any ideas I've tried adding a bunch of different 'onXXXX' triggers but none seem to trigger on ios using chrome when pressing the 'Done' button above the keyboard.
The reason I'm working on this is my handleBlur function sets the state of the keyboard (setKeyVisable(false))
which controls whether or not the site rescales - ie I don't want the site to resize when the keyboard is active
